In my browser console window.crossOriginIsolated is false despite of adding all proper COOP COEP CORP headers in my React Js and Django app
when i access cmd to express -> node server.js with COOP and COEP and corp headers and access directly the locahost:8080/ everything is working fine and even window.crossOriginIsolated is true. but when i integrate it to my existing react js and django and i add custom middleware.py for coop and coep. but still no use. even the pages of any of my reactjs and django itself is not showing window.crossOriginIsolated true despite of adding all required headers. i don't have any cors error at all my app works fine with apis. transaction between react js and django working fine.
this is custom middleware for cors:
from django.http import HttpResponse

class CrossOriginIsolationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Handle OPTIONS preflight request (for CORS)
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            response = HttpResponse()
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'  # Specify the frontend origin
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
            return response

        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'              
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'

        if request.path.startswith('/dicomweb/'):
            response['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin'
            response['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp'
            response['Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy'] = 'cross-origin'  # Changed to same-origin for better isolation
        elif request.path.startswith('/api/'):
            response['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin'
            response['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp'
            response['Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy'] = 'cross-origin'

        return response

my settings.py have:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'main.middleware.CrossOriginIsolationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
]

How to get window.crossOriginIsolated to true. i’m learning coding step by step. i dont know what im doing wrong.

Please clean up the question a bit., proper formatting makes it a lot easier to read. Please also restructure the text to make it clearer what the actual problem is - when stating the problem, don't weave in details about unrelated things. Also, from one of your React pages, console.log() the headers of the api response and verify that they are as expected. If the page is receiving the correct headers, then this is probably not a Django problem but rather an Express/Node/React problem.

sorry this is my first post. my headers for all the pages have correct COOP COEP. eg: http://localhost:8000/api/view-news/  access-control-allow-credentials: true. access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE. access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000 content-type:application/json  cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp cross-origin-opener-policy:same-origin cross-origin-resource-policy:cross-origin referrer-policy:same-origin server: daphne x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

sorry if it looks clumsy.. also i added "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",  proxy in my react js side package.json

It's OK that this is your first post, but please edit it and clean it up. Also include the info you've now put in the comments, so that it's easier for other readers to get the full picture. As an aside, why are you proxying? If accessing the direct URL works as expected but the proxied URL does not, then you've further narrowed the problem.
